# Display date in short format (Apr 02)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datetime

There is a scenario in which I have to display the date in short format(dd-mmm)

for ex : 
the date selected is 2 April after selecting the above format it should be

```
before      after date format
02 April    Apr 02
15 December Dec 15
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyDate.ToString("MMM dd");  //Note: Caps on MMM
```

- `MMM` = [Abbreviated Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier)
- `dd` = [two-digit day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier)

Good References:

1. [Custom Date & Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
2. [Standard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) (won't help your specific situation)

Comment: what you specified will provide the full month but i needed it in this format APR 02 not in this April 02 i hope you got the thing now.

Comment: I fixed it -- sorry for the mistake. Note the change to "MMM"

Comment: "MMM" The abbreviated name of the month will format 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM to Jun (en-US)